# AuthenticationProvider & Bean @PostConstruct ordering

Tags: spring

For a login page, I have an authentication method as:

```
@Component(value = "customSpringAuthentication")
public class CustomSpringAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

         ...

         return authUser;
    }
}
```

Also I have a bean, which is called after authentication:

```
@Component(value = "loggedinUserBean")
@Scope("session")
public class LoggedinUserBean {
    private AuthUser authUser;
    private boolean isAdminUser = false;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initModel() {

        ....
        authUser = (AuthUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        ....
    }
}
```

My question is when I am trying to access "authUser" in initmodel()method, it is null.
I know that authenticate method did not return null. But somewhat I realized that initmodel() works few miliseconds before authenticate returns. So that it can't get authetication object properly. How can I ensure/define ordering that without authenticate() returns loggedinuser is not initalized?

Comment: Why is your authenticate method marked as deprecated?

Comment: Ohh, it was someones code, I forgot to review it. It is obsolete & I don't it is something meaningful currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually answer your question, the `initModel()` method will be run immediately after your LoggedinUserBean object is created. This doesn't mean that its initialised. Initialisation and creation are two separate things. When an object is created, the JVM allocates memory for that object and all its fields. All the fields are null because they don't have values but the memory is set aside for you to populate the fields. Initialisation means that `authUser` will not be null because you have given it a value and you will only give it a value when `authenticate()` is called. As long as you aren't setting `authUser` anywhere else, then you are fine.

TL;DR: Its already guaranteed by Spring Security that your `authUser` is null until the user successfully authenticates using one of your authentication providers. If `authUser` remains null after then entire `springSecurityFilterChain` has been tried then the login attempt has failed.

Comment: In the above case, initModel is entered before authenticate returns.

Comment: yes, thats what i'm saying. You shouldn't be trying to get the value of the Authentication object because it hasn't been created or initialised yet

Comment: You should be creating your `LoggedinUserBean` from the `CustomSpringAuthentication` class and setting `AuthUser` there

Comment: In the above case, initModel is entered when authenticate is being executed but before authenticate returns when logging in. So in "initModel"  when I try to acquire authUser, I get a null, by milliseconds. I expect sequential execution between them actually it seems that is not the case. What may I be missing?

Comment: thats probably a better question

Comment: But what I expect is a sequential execution. I am clearly disappointted if Spring is not doing it that way. Before authentication returns, there must not be a bean initialization (@PostConstruct) for the forwarded LoggedInUserBean page.

Comment: Could you pleas @bahadir_g mention what is the solution I have the same problem